# How do I determine which side of the player has collided with an object?

Tags: xna, c#, physics, farseer-physics-engine

I have some static bodies (platforms) and a dynamic body (the player) in my world. The collision between them works great, but I would like to know which side of the player (rectangle) collides with the platform. How do I get this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this question was already answered but I needed this in one of my games as well and I found the answer in the Farseer forums and modified it for my engine. You will find the original link in the comments
(Shameless link to engine http://code.google.com/p/axiosengine/ - perhaps you will find more interesting things there)
:

```
namespace Axios.Engine.Extensions
{
    public enum CollisionDirection
    {
        Right,
        Left,
        Top,
        Bottom
    }
    public static class AxiosExtensions_Contact
    {
        /// http://farseerphysics.codeplex.com/discussions/281783
        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the direction that the collision happened.
        /// Should be used in the event OnAfterCollision
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="c"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static CollisionDirection Direction(this Contact c)
        {
            CollisionDirection direction;
            // Work out collision direction
            Vector2 colNorm = c.Manifold.LocalNormal;
            if (Math.Abs(colNorm.X) > Math.Abs(colNorm.Y))
            {
                // X direction is dominant
                if (colNorm.X > 0)
                    direction = CollisionDirection.Right;
                else
                    direction = CollisionDirection.Left;
            }
            else
            {
                // Y direction is dominant
                if (colNorm.Y > 0)
                    direction = CollisionDirection.Bottom;
                else
                    direction = CollisionDirection.Top;

            }

            return direction;
        }
    }
}
```

To use it:

```
 switch (contact.Direction())
                {
                    case CollisionDirection.Left:
//ect
```

Comment: I've had issues (in Farseer) with using the Contact's normal. As I said in my answer, you should probably use the WorldManifold.

Comment: I have not had a chance to do extensive testing on it, but it seems to work great on a rectangle shaped body. You may be right though - it might give wrong answers on more complex shapes - or even one that was created by a decomposer algorithm.

Comment: Are you talking about in Farseer or in your physics library? Because I doubt it's going to be the same.

Comment: I don't think I understand that question. In my engine the only physics engine I use is Farseer and that is what I was referencing in my comment. Would you like for me to include a more indepth example in my answer?

Comment: You said the engine you use is called "axios engine" and you modified an example from Farseer for that.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few ways I can think of to do this:

1. You could make the player into several fixtures representing each side. Then you could either give each one an `OnCollision` event, or give each one an ID in the `UserData` to figure out which one is the "collider" in a shared `OnCollision` method. This was good for me because I could set the side and top fixtures to have zero friction so the player doesn't stick to platforms.
2. If you're stuff is all axis aligned rectangles, you could calculate it based on their positions and dimensions. This is probably not a great idea for more complex situations since it can get difficult to follow and Farseer already has to calculate this anyways.
3. I think you can check the `Contact`'s world manifold's normal. In your `OnContact` event, there are three parameters: two `Fixtures` and a `Contact`. `Contact` has a method called `GetWorldManifold` which has an `out` parameter called `normal`. This is a `Vector2` that, I think (someone please correct me if I'm wrong), represents the angle of contact.

Comment: Is it possible to get the information how much farseer rotates the object etc? this soloutions look very complicated :D

Comment: @Michael - I'm not sure about that. I think you can only get the points of contact and the normal, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Knows anyone else if there is a option in farseer?

Comment: @Michael - I don't think that the object will have rotated at all on contact. The contact happens when the first point of one `Fixture` overlaps another. After that happens, the bodies, depending on the collision, may rotate, but it will be a different value each iteration of the `Update`. So, what you could do is store the body's rotation from the initial collision event `OnCollision` and then on other iterations of the loop, you can subtract the current rotation of the body from that value to figure out how much it has been rotated. This wouldn't really work if you have multiple collisions.

Comment: Yeah so thanks for your answer I am going to try the way with the fixtures on every side. I am a beginner so I haven't worked with fixtures yet. If you have a good tutorial I would be glad!

Comment: @Michael - Unfortunately I don't. But keep in mind that Farseer is based off  of box2d so if you find a box2d tutorial, you can probably translate some of it to Farseer. Regarding fixtures: every body in your `World` is made up of at least one `Fixture`. The fixtures are the things that collide with one another while the `Body` keeps track of it's fixtures and handles the rotation and position and some other important properties. That's why the `OnCollision` passes in `Fixture`s and not `Body`s. Also, a word of warning, if you make fixtures too thin they may tunnel through objects, be careful.

Comment: I made my Player so:  
body = BodyFactory.CreateRectangle(world, (float)ConvertUnits.ToSimUnits(playertexture.Width), (float)ConvertUnits.ToSimUnits(playertexture.Height), 1f);
            body.BodyType = BodyType.Dynamic;
            body.Position = new Vector2(ConvertUnits.ToSimUnits(position.X), ConvertUnits.ToSimUnits(position.Y));
            body.Mass = 1f;

Comment: Please help me!

Comment: @Michael - What are you asking for help with?